# Why is the heading message not displayed in the console?

Tags: c#

Why is this Method not working here? I want it to display the heading message this way but why is it not displaying it?

```
using System;

namespace rd
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            setget sgobj = new setget();
            login _login = new login();
            Console.WriteLine(sgobj.heading);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class setget
    {
        public string heading
        { set; get; }
    }

    class login
    {
        setget setobj = new setget();
        public void header_message()
        {
            setobj.heading= "*************************************************************************************"+
                "\n*************************************************************************************"+
                "\n*************************                             *******************************"+
                "\n************************* Welcome to Radeon Limited.. *******************************"+
                "\n*************************                             *******************************"+
                "\n*************************************************************************************"+
                "\n*************************************************************************************";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: call _login.header_message() before printing the message

Answer (score 3):

You have multiple issues here:

- You set the `heading` property within the `header_message` method but you never call that method. So the value for `setobj.heading` within the `login` object is never changed and null by default.
- You create a `setget` object in your `Main` method and you also create a `login` object there, but the `login` object has its own `setget` object so even if you changed the value, it would not affect the `setget` object you created. The values are not linked.

You should do it something like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SetGet sgobj = new SetGet();

        // pass your SetGet object to the login constructor
        Login login = new Login(sgobj);

        // call the method to set the login message
        login.header_message();

        // print the login message
        Console.WriteLine(sgobj.Heading);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class SetGet
{
    public string Heading
    { set; get; }
}

class Login
{
    private SetGet setobj;

    // accept a SetGet object and store it in the login instance
    public Login (SetGet setobj)
    {
        this.setobj = setobj;
    }

    public void header_message()
    {
        setobj.Heading= "*************************************************************************************"+
            "\n*************************************************************************************"+
            "\n*************************                             *******************************"+
            "\n************************* Welcome to Radeon Limited.. *******************************"+
            "\n*************************                             *******************************"+
            "\n*************************************************************************************"+
            "\n*************************************************************************************";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

make the classes `public` and you have to call `_login.header_message()`  then `Console.WriteLine(_login.setobj.heading);` and you dont have to use `setget sgobj = new setget();` in main

```
namespace rd
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            login _login = new login();
            _login.header_message();
            Console.WriteLine(_login.setobj.heading);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class setget
    {
        public string heading
        { set; get; }
    }

    public class login
    {
        public setget setobj = new setget();
        public void header_message()
        {
            setobj.heading= "*************************************************************************************"+
                "\n*************************************************************************************"+
                "\n*************************                             *******************************"+
                "\n************************* Welcome to Radeon Limited.. *******************************"+
                "\n*************************                             *******************************"+
                "\n*************************************************************************************"+
                "\n*************************************************************************************";
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: That will not be enough as OP is not accessing the `setget` object inside the `_login` (it’s private).

Answer (score 0):

Since the string heading is initialized by calling the method `header_message()`, you will need to call the method, before using the string `heading`.
You can initialize this in the constructor of the `setget` class. That way, the `heading` will always be initialized and ready to use.

Answer (score 0):

Because You use instance of `sgobj` object whitch  have `heading` object empty.

Answer (score 0):

it's because you're declaring one setget object in your main and one in the header_message(); and only assigning the string to the one within the message. So for the sake of this example I returned the object set in the method and assigned it to your one in the main.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        setget sgobj = new setget();
        login _login = new login();
        sgobj = _login.header_message();
        Console.WriteLine(sgobj.heading);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    class setget
    {
        public string heading
        { set; get; }
    }

    class login
    {
        setget setobj = new setget();
        public setget header_message()
        {
            setobj.heading = "*************************************************************************************" +
                "\n*************************************************************************************" +
                "\n*************************                             *******************************" +
                "\n************************* Welcome to Radeon Limited.. *******************************" +
                "\n*************************                             *******************************" +
                "\n*************************************************************************************" +
                "\n*************************************************************************************";

            return setobj;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's my exact code and it's outputting the string to the console, what's the header_message method returning for you?